# Can there be two blocks with the same number?

Tags: blockchain, blocks

I am trying to index blockchain data and I am thinking of what's a unique way to identify a block.

Is it enough to use block number as the primary identifier and is there a possibility that the data associated with block may change in the future?

If block number on its own is not enough, what other information should I include to form a unique constraint?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the block hash. For example block number 12551600 :
https://etherscan.io/block/12551600

```
Hash : 0x1856e857565089091ef6ab0bb193b15302f293b33c5a432b8fbdb51cedfe1ad3
```

Block height is unique yes, but sometimes there is "re-org" on blockchain as you can see in this link :

https://etherscan.io/blocks_forked

For example, there is another block number 12551600 :

https://etherscan.io/block/12551600/f       *Note the extra "/f" at link's end.*

```
Hash : 0x8e5fb29a9046c36dca0b1812f775b51c3e5170644e8e2177f867c7f8f53505d8
```

This block was not accepted. I think few times per hour when miners found block at the same time, and the stronger is picked by the network.

So take the hash because it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have two blocks with the same number. However, only one will be valid. To determine which one is valid, you have to wait for a few blocks to be mined after the double blocks (this is called waiting for *confirmation*). The longest chain built on top of one of the two blocks will be considered the canonical chain.

Block number is **not** a unique identifier. The block **hash** is its unique identifier.

See this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/99675/42354) for a practical approach to indexing.